# Изменение кода уже скомпилированной программы

Tags: c, компилятор, exe

Здравствуйте! Только что задался вопросом: можно ли изменить код уже скомпилированной программы(так чтобы она работала)? То есть, имея исполняемый файл, можно ли его открыть как текстовый документ и изменять(ну всё-таки исходные коды линковщиков и компиляторов есть же). Я понимаю, что после работы компилятора, си там уже не пахнет, но всё же, изучив структуру `ехе` файла - это можно сделать, или это полный бред?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59437/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 6):

Полностью исходный код программы конечно получить не возможно, но есть декомпиляторы которые его стараются восстановить, но получается из этого вырви-глаз и разбирать там не чего, а тем более редактировать. Насчёт редактирования ПО, это вам нужно изучить ассемблер (советую гуглить по запросу "реверс инжиниринг") и научиться таким программам как OllyDbg либо IdaPRO (платная и достаточно дороговатая) и потом уже делать патчи на те программы которые вы хотите, точнее редактировать. Но есть проблема в вашем вопросе, как вы хотите её редактировать, если просто дизайн, то вам достаточно и редактора ресурсов, которых OVER 9999+ в интернете как бесплатных(Resource Hacker), так и платных(Resource Tuner).

Comment: Да нет, Вы просто не поняли моего вопроса, из-за его абсурдности. Можно ли, **теоретически** менять код уже скомпилированного экзешника блокнотом каким-нибудь, при условии, идеального знания роботы компилятора и линковщика?

Comment: @АртурКлочко да, конечно, если вы машина , то вы можете редактировать через какой нибудь текстовый редактор опкоды программы и менять ход её работы

Comment: а я однажды блокнотом создал экзешник и подписал его `time`, а внутри просто какие-то свои данные записал. В итоге я запустил экзешник, открылось окно консоли и показало мне время. Ещё раз повторюсь в экзешнике даже MZ не пахло, просто несколько строк. Как так? Какая фича Винды?

Comment: @АртурКлочко, командный интерпретатор обработал и запустил команду time. Делов-то. `exe` тут как флаг исполнения, а не машинный код.

Comment: @0andriy, понял, спасибо!

Comment: @АртурКлочко не знаю, что за читерские приёмы у вас, но я знаю что раньше либо на Dos, либо на XP можно было просто ввести опкоды-инструкций без определения PE структуры программы и запустить просто запустить прогу и она работала, это сейчас уже на win10,8 уже не грузит, а раньше можно было

Comment: @0andriy, в смысле? Вообще без заголовков и т.д.? Просто опкоды-инструкции пишешь и запускаешь? А на 7ке прокатит?

Comment: @АртурКлочко хз, не пробовал когда стояла :( Вряд-ли.

Comment: @0andriy блин, вот это сейчас было вообще интересно, пойду гуглить

Comment: @0andriy вы имеете ввиду что @АртурКлочко сохранил батник с командой `time`?

Comment: @0andriy 1) Не батник, а экзешник. 2) Нет, гуглить про возможность ввода опкод-инструкций в толи xp, толи dos`e

Comment: @АртурКлочко На сколько я понимаю все винды для совместимости продолжают поддерживать `com` файлы. А com это и есть голый набор опкодов без всяких заголовков. И загрузчик при расширении файла exe если не увидит PE или MZ заголовка скорее всего посчитает его com-ом

Comment: Осталось только ассемблер, а потом и опкоды, выучить

Answer (score 3):

Через конкретно блокнот (или там Word) - нет, запорет он вам некоторые символы...
А вот hex-редактором - в принципе можно. А как, по-вашему, всякие ломалки работают? :) Именно так - меняя в нужных местах код/данные.
Только тут - как в том апокрифе со старшим Капицей, которому якобы обещали за границей 10000 марок за ремонт какой-то там установки. Он приехал, посмотрел, сказал ассистенту ударить молотком в таком-то месте - все заработало. За такую работу принимающей стороне сумма показалась слишком большой, попросили счет. Он выглядел так:

Удар молотком - 1 марка.
За то что знал, где ударить - 9999 марок.

Словом, чтоб знать, куда ударить и какие байты и как поменять - надо долго и упорно учиться :)

Поменять какие-то данные типа, чтоб не Hello world выводила, а типа  Coolhacker :) - это попроще...